# How to pass data from HTML page to PHP script without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

**Goal:** I want to Hide "myForm" div when data successfully post to the database and the "section" div will show component when submit button will clicked, its working properly.

**Problem / Requirement:** Problem is that data not posting to the database, how can i solve this problem to save data to the database and show / hide div after that database operation.

**Note:** I don't want to reload my page.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="section" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae cupiditate culpa reprehenderit animi,
        numquam distinctio repellendus debitis fugit unde consequatur eum magni illo minima amet quidem omnis veniam
        commodi voluptatum!
    </p>
</div>
<div id="myForm">
    <form id="testForm" method="post" action="#">
        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-send" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
const sectionDiv = document.getElementById('section');
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Please suggest the flow and code for call PHP script from here

    form.style.display = 'none';
    sectionDiv.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Please suggest flow and process in above Javascript code for how to pass my data to below PHP script..

**PHP Code:**

```
include("db.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $form_name=  $_POST['name'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `test` (`xxname`) VALUES ('$form_name')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
    {
        echo "asdfghjkl";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $query. " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: use AJAX to send the data to the PHP script ( to save to db ) and use the `callback` to hide the form

Comment: Hi. Try in the form, have an input box but with the style of display:none

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass your client request to server side through AJAX, call your server script using AJAX from your javascript code function:

```
const sectionDiv = document.getElementById('section');
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let serData = form[0].serialize();

    // Add your AJAX Code here
    $.ajax({
        url: "/form.php", // your PHP script's file name
        type: "post",
        data: serData, // pass your fields here 
        success: function(data){
            // do your actions here 
            // you can put your condition here like if( data.status == true ) then success other wise failure
            form.style.display = 'none';
            sectionDiv.style.display = 'block';
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
             // console your error here
             console.log(error);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using pure javascript. You can send post request to server by using XMLHttpRequest.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/your-request-path', true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
      if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
         form.style.display = 'none';
         sectionDiv.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    xhr.send("your form data");

});
```

For reference xmlhttprequest you may visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send this url.

Answer (score -2):

Using the `fetch` api for simplicity and brevity - an example piece of code that will make a POST request to the server ( in this instance the same page but change `location.href` for the correct endpoint / url ) and use the `callback` to perform the DOM manipulation.

The PHP at the top here is to emulate YOUR database insert - you would be advised however to use a `prepared statement` rather than embedding user content directly in the SQL as this leaves you vulnerable to SQL Injection.

```
<?php

    # include scripts
    require 'db.php';


    /*
        The PHP endpoint that handles the database insert.
        For the purposes of this example it is on the same
        page as the HTML form but can as easily be a different
        script.
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /*
            Only process this piece if there is a POST request with
            a particular parameter present in the request. Note that
            it makes more sense to test that the parameter that will 
            be used in any database operations is present as opposed
            to the `submit` button which is commonly used for such a 
            test but serves no purpose beyond this point so is redundant.
        */
        if( isset( $_POST['name'] ) ){
            /*
                As this is an AJAX request we are only interested in
                content generated in this piece of code. Anything that
                was generated before or after should be discarded.
            */
            ob_flush();


            /* 
                Create a "Prepared Statement" to allow the user 
                supplied data to be handled in a safe manner. Note
                that you should not use `mysqli_real_escape_string`
            */
            $sql='insert into `test` ( `xxname` ) values ( ? )';
            $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

            /*
                The return value from the `prepare` method is a Boolean
                so you are able to use that value to "Fork" the program
                logic.
            */
            if( $stmt ){
                /*
                    The prepared statement has been created by the server
                    so now you can assign values to the placeholders. This
                    is done using `bind_param`

                    Different types of variable can be bound using a different
                    `type` argument
                        >   i   - integers
                        >   s   - strings
                        >   d   - double
                        >   b   - boolean
                */
                $stmt->bind_param( 's', $_POST['name'] );
                /*
                    With the variable bound to the placeholder
                    you can now commit the data to the db
                */
                $result=$stmt->execute();
                $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
                /*
                    The return value from `execute` is a boolean. 
                    It will be false if, for some reason, the db
                    failed to process the request.

                    To determine if the request succeeded you can use
                    a combination of $result & $rows if you wish and
                    inform the user with an appropriate response.
                */
                $response = $result && $rows==1 ? 'Whoohoo! Record added - ya dancer!' : 'ERROR: Could not insert record';
                exit( $response );
            }else{
                /*
                    If you get here it often suggests a syntax error in 
                    the sql. You could use $stmt->error to aid analysis
                    but not in production code.
                */
                exit('bogus');
            }
        }

        /* To prevent the whole page appearing in the AJAX response */
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Submit Form data and hide form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- slightly streamlined version of original HTML markup. -->
        <div style='display:none;'>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae cupiditate culpa reprehenderit animi,
                numquam distinctio repellendus debitis fugit unde consequatur eum magni illo minima amet quidem omnis veniam
                commodi voluptatum!
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form method='post'>
                <input type='text' name='name' />
                <input type='submit' />
            </form>
        </div>


        <script>
            /*
                Bind an event handler to the submit ( or regular ) button to fire
                an AJAX request to the PHP server.

                Binding a FORM with the `submit` event requires a different approach
                to that shown in the question. The callback function or event handler
                needs to return a boolean and the form will only be submitted if the
                function evaluates to true. Hence better binding to the button as we
                do not want to send the form in the traditional sense - we need to 
                fashion our own request without reloading the page.
            */
            document.querySelector('form > input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                // Prevent the form being submitted.
                e.preventDefault();

                /* 
                    using parent and sibling selectors we can identify 
                    the required DOM elements that will be used in the
                    show/hide operations.  
                */
                let container=this.parentNode.parentNode;
                let div=container.previousElementSibling;

                /*
                    The `Fetch` api was developed to provide greater
                    flexibility than the more commonly used `XMLHttpRequest`
                    which has become the workhorse of many web applications.

                    To explain it fully you should study the documentation on
                    MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
                    Google - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

                    Another little gem is the `FormData` object used here.
                    MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData


                    The fetch call sends the request in this case to the same page ( location.href )
                    and has various configuration options set - method and body being of interest.

                    The `body` of the request is the `FormData` object which can be populated
                    automagically by supplying a reference to the FORM as the argument or manually
                    by calling the `append` method.

                    rtfm
                */
                fetch( location.href, { method:'post',body:( new FormData( document.querySelector('form') ) ) } )
                    .then( response=>{ return response.text() } )
                    .then( text=>{
                        /* The server response can be read / used here */
                        console.info( text );

                        /* perform the show and hide operations... */
                        container.style.display='none';
                        div.style.display='block';
                    })
                    .catch( err=>{ alert(err) })                

            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe if you showed how to implement parameter binding it would be less. Also try to explain your code a little bit more.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it many ways. I made this very simple way using Ajax with a single php file. You need to send the data via ajax and need to catch that using PHP. You can try the below code.

Note: Please make sure you have changed the your connection name, password and db name

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Insert Data from html form to MySQL Database using Ajax and PHP</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="message" style="display: none;">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam quo ex pariatur aliquid vero!
                Voluptatibus harum accusamus amet maiores at sit, neque magni nulla ut optio quis culpa nisi nostrum!
            </p>
        </div>
        <form id="myForm">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" id="btn-save" />
        </form>

        <script>
            const submit = $('#btn-save').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                const name = $('#name').val();

                if(!name) return alert('Please enter your name');

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { name: name },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.message').show();
                        $('#myForm').hide();
                    },
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","mydb");

    // Checking connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // If the form data found save and send response
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`( `name`) VALUES ('$name')";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>200)); 
        }
        else { 
            echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201)); 
        } 
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```